# 7938 LEGO train not working (not cargo train)

Tags: trains

My son Joel has his 7938 train built but it's not working! Have batteries in battery box & remote control-HELP please! New batteries-assembled properly.

Comment: Hi Lorraine, and welcome. For us to be able to help you and answer your questions, you would need to provide some more details, for example pictures of the train and how it's assembled, as well as more specific information as to how it is "not working". Does the light on the remote control light up? Does the light on the battery box light up?

Comment: All the lights, light up.  Assembled correctly. New Duracell batteries in properly.

Comment: Is the remote control set to the same channel as the receiver on the train?

Comment: Yes, the remote control is set to the same channel as the receiver on the train.

Comment: I finally got it working with yet another set of brand new Duracell batteries-the fault was with Duracell!